# If $1\in M$, could $M$ be a maximal ideal of a commutative ring with identity $R$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

> If $1\in M$, could $M$ be a maximal ideal of a commutative ring with identity $R$?

I know that this is a very silly question. I think that the answer is that $M$ can't contain the identity for the product, because if it does, then $M=R$ and then it wouldn't be a maximal ideal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your thoughts are on the mark.

For *any* ideal $I$ in *any* ring $R$, commutative or not, we have

$1_R \in I \Rightarrow I = R, \tag{1}$

since in the case $1_R \in I$ we have, for *any* $r \in R$,

$r = 1_R r = r1_R \in I.  \tag{2}$

Now *maximal* ideals $M$ are generally defined to be *proper*, that is, $M \subsetneq R$; this precludes $1_R \in M$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. Here is an algebraic manipulation of this.

Let $r \in R$,

$$1 \in M \Rightarrow 1 \cdot r = r \in M$$
So $R \subseteq M \Rightarrow R = M$